# How to integrate gate2play in iOS

Tags: ios, payment-gateway

I have hit a glass wall while attempting to integrate `gate2play` in an iOS app. the documentation is deficient for iOS and web search is also getting no were.Has any one integrated `gate2play` in iOS apps.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to answer my own question and the sole moto behind this one is to save others time.

This is what i know now gate2play works this way on iOS

1. Hit a post request to get token for transaction.
2. Load a Webview with HTML and the received token for the transaction use a redirect URL.
3. Catch the redirect url in web view delgate method and hit a get request with the same token to get the status of the transaction.

I have compiled the sum total of my entire days effort into a step by step procedure and i welcome improvements. [here is the link](http://codefriends.blogspot.in/2014/02/gate2play-and-ios-integration.html)